# 0 * Negative number is't returning 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer with slope physics in unity, so I'm using this code to make the player move at the correct speed on the ground.

```
velocity.x = Mathf.Sin(groundAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * groundSpeed;`  
velocity.y = Mathf.Cos(groundAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * groundSpeed;
```

The problem is, for some odd reason when I move left, (groundSpeed is negative) velocity.y becomes something like 0.0000006, which screws up a ton of other code.

How do I fix this Unity math wierdness?

Here's what I'm trying to replicate: http://info.sonicretro.org/SPG:Slope_Physics#The_Three_Speed_Variables

Comment: What is `groundAngle`? Have you checked to see if `Mathf.Cos(groundAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)` is also negative?

Comment: What do you want to fix? What is your desired result? May be use [Math.Abs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=net-6.0).

Comment: "groundSpeed is negative" - how the absolute value (which is what groundSpeed is based on the formula shown) can be negative? It is possible you are talking about x/y *projections* of the speed vector - but it is not what code says.

Comment: Re-reading your post I suspect that you implemented 180 turn as speed = -speed (implying that speed has only X component with Y is always zero)... which would be ok if it is *the only* rotation transformation. You may want to write proper physics code instead of hacking parts...

Comment: _"How do I fix this **Unity math wierdness?**"_ - Unity has nothing to do with it.  Your velocity calculation **is not making use of any Unity physics**.  If anything it resembles something from XNA times.   If in your Unity game you are using rigid bodies and then proceed to calculate physics yourself like acceleration (inc gravity), velocity etc then you _are doing it wrong._

Comment: @MickyD I'm pretty sure Unity is involved because of the Mathf.Cos(groundAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), because Mathf is part of Unity (or at least I think it is). Also I am not using any rigidbodies.

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure Unity is involved because of the Mathf.Cos"_ - **1)** you'll note I actually said _"Your velocity calculation is not making use of any **Unity physics**"_.  Trigonometric functions is **not** _"physics"_. I see no forces above. Your code above if anything is probably just vector math. **2)** Incidentally, Unity's `Mathf.Cos` actually ultimately calls `System.Math` in the .NET Framework.  Here's Unity's code: `public static float Cos(float f) => (float) Math.Cos((double) f);` **3)** _"Also I am not using any rigidbodies"_ - as I pointed out under the answer below you should be

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: @MickyD Huh, i totally thought mathf.cos was unity math, huh. The reason I don't want to use Unity's rigidbodies is because I'm trying to recreate what's in the link I added to my post, and I feel rigidbodies would be too finiky to replicate that.

Comment: Well it turns out I completely misjudged what the problem was. I fixed it.